# Qt: How to change cursor by using style sheets?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, mouse-cursor

I know I can change the cursor by `"setCursor(const QCursor &)"`.

Now I want to change it by using qss, but I don't know how to do it.

QWidget has the cursor property, so theoretically I can use `"qproperty-cursor:PointingHandCursor"` to set cursor. But it doesn't work!

Does anyone know why "qproperty-cursor" doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done because `QCursor` is not an enum but a class (of which each existing cursor like `Qt::PointingHandCursor` is a global instantiation, the same as `std::cout` is a global instantiation of `std::ostream`), and there are no conversion available between a string and existing cursor instantiations.